# Can't install rtl8191su driver on my Lenovo Z580

Tags: wireless, drivers

First of all I'm new to linux so i need step by step tutorial :)

I bought AirLive WN-380 USB wireless adapter, and when i connect him with my laptop (Lenovo Z580) Ubuntu doesn't recognize him, even the led light doesn't flash. I know it has RTL 8191SU chipset inside and i downloaded the newest driver from Realtek and i cant install it. I have tried many tutorials but they are all for experienced users and i don't understand them quite well..
Every time i try i got an error when doing "make" command, "sudo make" doesn't work either,it has became very frustrating. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I got this:

```
$ make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-35-generic/build M=/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-35-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.o
In file included from /home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c:23:0:
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘_init_timer’:
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/osdep_service.h:151:17: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
  ptimer->data = (u32)cntx;
                 ^
In file included from /home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c:23:0:
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘thread_enter’:
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/osdep_service.h:393:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘daemonize’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  daemonize("%s", "RTKTHREAD");
  ^
In file included from /home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/rtl871x_ht.h:25:0,
                 from /home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/drv_types.h:67,
                 from /home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c:24:
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h: In function ‘get_da’:
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:324:46: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
 #define GetAddr1Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 4))
                                              ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:350:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr1Ptr’
    da = GetAddr1Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:324:28: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
 #define GetAddr1Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 4))
                            ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:350:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr1Ptr’
    da = GetAddr1Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:324:46: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
 #define GetAddr1Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 4))
                                              ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:353:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr1Ptr’
    da = GetAddr1Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:324:28: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
 #define GetAddr1Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 4))
                            ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:353:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr1Ptr’
    da = GetAddr1Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:328:46: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
 #define GetAddr3Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 16))
                                              ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:356:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr3Ptr’
    da = GetAddr3Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:328:28: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
 #define GetAddr3Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 16))
                            ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:356:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr3Ptr’
    da = GetAddr3Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:328:46: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
 #define GetAddr3Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 16))
                                              ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:359:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr3Ptr’
    da = GetAddr3Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:328:28: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
 #define GetAddr3Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 16))
                            ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:359:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr3Ptr’
    da = GetAddr3Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h: In function ‘get_sa’:
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:326:46: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
 #define GetAddr2Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 10))
                                              ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:374:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr2Ptr’
    sa = GetAddr2Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:326:28: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
 #define GetAddr2Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 10))
                            ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:374:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr2Ptr’
    sa = GetAddr2Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:328:46: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
 #define GetAddr3Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 16))
                                              ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:377:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr3Ptr’
    sa = GetAddr3Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:328:28: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
 #define GetAddr3Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 16))
                            ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:377:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr3Ptr’
    sa = GetAddr3Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:326:46: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
 #define GetAddr2Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 10))
                                              ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:380:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr2Ptr’
    sa = GetAddr2Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:326:28: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
 #define GetAddr2Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 10))
                            ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:380:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr2Ptr’
    sa = GetAddr2Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:330:46: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
 #define GetAddr4Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 24))
                                              ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:383:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr4Ptr’
    sa = GetAddr4Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:330:28: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
 #define GetAddr4Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 24))
                            ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:383:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr4Ptr’
    sa = GetAddr4Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h: In function ‘get_hdr_bssid’:
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:328:46: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
 #define GetAddr3Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 16))
                                              ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:397:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr3Ptr’
    sa = GetAddr3Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:328:28: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
 #define GetAddr3Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 16))
                            ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:397:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr3Ptr’
    sa = GetAddr3Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:326:46: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
 #define GetAddr2Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 10))
                                              ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:400:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr2Ptr’
    sa = GetAddr2Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:326:28: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
 #define GetAddr2Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 10))
                            ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:400:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr2Ptr’
    sa = GetAddr2Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:324:46: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
 #define GetAddr1Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 4))
                                              ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:403:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr1Ptr’
    sa = GetAddr1Ptr(pframe);
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:324:28: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
 #define GetAddr1Ptr(pbuf) ((unsigned char *)((unsigned int)(pbuf) + 4))
                            ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/wifi.h:403:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘GetAddr1Ptr’
    sa = GetAddr1Ptr(pframe);
         ^
In file included from /home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/drv_types.h:70:0,
                 from /home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c:24:
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/rtl871x_cmd.h: At top level:
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/rtl871x_cmd.h:107:25: error: field ‘event_tasklet’ has incomplete type
   struct tasklet_struct event_tasklet;
                         ^
In file included from /home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/drv_types.h:72:0,
                 from /home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c:24:
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/rtl871x_xmit.h:355:24: error: field ‘xmit_tasklet’ has incomplete type
  struct tasklet_struct xmit_tasklet;
                        ^
In file included from /home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/drv_types.h:73:0,
                 from /home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c:24:
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/rtl871x_recv.h:205:24: error: field ‘recv_tasklet’ has incomplete type
  struct tasklet_struct recv_tasklet;
                        ^
In file included from /home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/drv_types.h:73:0,
                 from /home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c:24:
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/rtl871x_recv.h: In function ‘rxmem_to_recvframe’:
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/rtl871x_recv.h:435:30: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
  return (union recv_frame*)(((uint)rxmem>>RXFRAME_ALIGN) <<RXFRAME_ALIGN) ;
                              ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/include/rtl871x_recv.h:435:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
  return (union recv_frame*)(((uint)rxmem>>RXFRAME_ALIGN) <<RXFRAME_ALIGN) ;
         ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c: In function ‘_init_cmd_priv’:
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c:93:75: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
  pcmdpriv->cmd_buf = pcmdpriv->cmd_allocated_buf  +  CMDBUFF_ALIGN_SZ - ( (uint)(pcmdpriv->cmd_allocated_buf) & (CMDBUFF_ALIGN_SZ-1));
                                                                           ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c:101:60: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
  pcmdpriv->rsp_buf = pcmdpriv->rsp_allocated_buf  +  4 - ( (uint)(pcmdpriv->rsp_allocated_buf) & 3);
                                                            ^
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c: In function ‘_init_evt_priv’:
/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.c:135:59: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
  pevtpriv->evt_buf = pevtpriv->evt_allocated_buf  +  4 - ((unsigned int)(pevtpriv->evt_allocated_buf) & 3);
                                                           ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/cmd/rtl871x_cmd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/ivimiha/Desktop/rtl/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/driver/rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-35-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

With dmesg | tail:

ivimiha@Batman:~$ dmesg | tail
[22402.349970] usb 1-1.1: Product: AirLive WN-380USB Adapter
[22402.349973] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Manufacturer Realtek 
[22402.349976] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
[22432.546867] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 9
[22435.819689] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[22435.914902] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1b75, idProduct=8172
[22435.914910] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[22435.914914] usb 1-1.1: Product: AirLive WN-380USB Adapter
[22435.914917] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Manufacturer Realtek 
[22435.914920] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001

Answer (score 0):

The Realtek website says the driver is for:

```
Linux Kernel 2.6.18~2.6.38 and Kernel 3.0.2
```

However, version 3.0.2 is pretty old. If you do `uname -r`, You'll see a version of about 3.13 (mine e.g. is 3.13.0-24). So this driver will not work.

But if Ubuntu doesn't even accept the USB, then it's certainly not an issue of the Wifi driver. RTL8191su should run with the preinstalled driver `r8712u`.

Please plug in the device and directly after that execute `dmesg | tail`. If there's anything USB-related, add it to your question.